# Applying attribute filter for join table in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables in spring boot application and they are join. when I get all the fields for it I get result as below :

{

```
"var1": "XYZREUF",
"var2": "2023-02-07T13:07:44.759+00:00",
"var3": "2023-02-07T13:07:44.759+00:00",
"var4": "2023-02-07T13:07:44.759+00:00",
"arr1": [
  {      
    "v1": null,
    "v2": null,
    "v3": "ABC",
    "v4": "XYZ",
    "v5": "FILENAM",
    "v6": "uniqnam"
  }
]
```

}
}

When I use JsonFilter I was able to filter out varible in json, but I am not able to filter out the attribute for the json array I am getting all the attribute for the table which is present. I am not able to filter out attribute present in json array.

I found one way to write separate query in the for the joined table, example below :
**@Query("SELECT w from tablenm w INNER JOIN w.clo u where u.num < ?1")
List functionForJoinTab(int v);**

But this is not dynamic I won't be able to fetch the attribute on the go.

I am expecting I could use JsonFilter for the joined table and able to fetched required attribute. Below example:

{

```
"var1": "XYZREUF",
"var4": "2023-02-07T13:07:44.759+00:00",
"arr1": [
  {
    "v5": "FILENAM",
    "v6": "uniqnam"
  }
]
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Ignore null fields with Jackson

try on class level:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class YourDto{
 ...
}
```

or

try on field level:

```
class YourDto{
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  private String yourField;
}
```